# Prove that this inequality holds true

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

The inequality I have in mind is $|\frac{e^{(x^2+y^2)} ~~- ~1}{x^2+y^2}-1| \leq M \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and $M>0, (x,y) \not= (0,0)$.

I am given a hint that if there are 3$^{rd}$ partial derivatives for $f(x,y)$ in a neighborhood $(a,b)$, then $|f(x,y)-T_{(a,b)}(x,y)| \leq M||(x,y)-(a,b)||^{k+1}$ is true where $M>0$. $T_{(a,b)}(x,y)$ is the taylor polynomial for a point $(a,b)$. The 2 lines || is the distance formula, so it would represent $\sqrt{(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2}$. These 2 equations are really similar and perhaps I just have to check that every condition holds so that there exists a $M>0$. Is there a way to check this (or prove the statement somehow?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a correct statement.

If you do the substitution $r \to \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then you get:
$$\left|\frac{e^{r^2}-1}{r^2}-1\right| \leq Mr$$

If you perform the Taylor expansion of $e^{r^2}$, you get:
$$e^{r^2} = 1 + r^2 + \frac{r^4}2 + O(r^6)$$

In this context, $O(r^6)$ and all other terms are positive. So we have that:
$$e^{r^2} \geq 1 + r^2 + \frac{r^4}2$$

You can substitute in your original relation and get:
$$\frac{r^2}2 \leq Mr$$

You can't find a $M$ that will satisfy this inequality.

Comment: I see, thanks..